# Where can I find abbreviations of kwargs in the matplotlib documentation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, keyword-argument

The documentation of various matplotlib methods lists all keyword arguments for each of those methods. 
Appreciating that, I fail to find any hints about the abbreviations avaiable for those keyword arguments.

For example it is possible to write the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # creates figure with axes
line, = ax.plot([1,2], [1,2], color='blue', lw=2)
```

When I look up the documentation of matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot I am able to find the keyword argument "linewidth". But there is no hint that this argument can be abbreviated with "lw".

Assuming I didn't know that "lw" stands for "linewidth" how am I supposed to find out?

Comment: The following [page](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) lists all the necessary kwargs.

Comment: You are right, they used to be part of the documentation, [now they are gone](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13278).